# Pattern for sequence of steps with no common interface

Tags: java, design-patterns

In my java app I got a method that runs a long sequence of steps (synchronously) where one step result is the input for the next.

for example:

```
// Step 1
Map<String, SomeObject> objectsMap = someService.createObjectsMap();
if (!objectsMap.isEmpty()) {
    // Step 2
    AnotherObject anotherObject = anotherService.createAnotherObject(objectsMap);
    if (null != anotherObject) {
    // Step 3 that gets anotherObject as input and returns something else
    } else { // Step 2 failed
        // log and handle
    }
} else { // Step 1 failed
    // log and handle
}
```

And so I got this series of steps written in a series of if-else blocks.
There is no common interface for the steps since each one has different signature. I've been loking on some different and tried to customize patterns such as [chain-of-responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) and [command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)  but could not get to a satisfied result.

I wonder if this ugly long if-else section is the way to go or is there a pattern out there that can help make this series of steps more clean and scalable.

Comment: It seems to do exactly what you want. (Well, you need `throw` as well)

Comment: I'm searching for a pattern to help me run all the steps, validate each step result and go on to the next step only if the previous one succeeded. It woks now, as is, but I simply don't like the way it is written. I don't see how using try/catch relates to my requirement

Comment: I answered, then deleted after re-reading your question. Are you looking for a way to describe the steps, return objects and calls using common types?

Comment: When dealing with different signatures shrink them to one parameter using a parameter object and then use generics.

Answer (score 12):

One question you must answer yourself is *Why do I want to refactor my code?*

Do you want it to be

- more clean code?
- more modularized?
- Must the steps be configurable (replaceable) at runtime?

**Refactor in order to make the code clean**

If the steps do not need to be configured at runtime and you want to make your code more clean than you should take a look at the comments you made. Each comment is a hint.

Break the code block into methods and name them after the steps

```
/**
 * Explain what step1 does.
 */
private void step1() {
    // Step 1
    Map<String, SomeObject> objectsMap = someService.createObjectsMap();
    if (!objectsMap.isEmpty()) {
        step2(objectsMap);
    } else { // Step 1 failed
        // log and handle
    }
}

/**
 * Explain what step2 does.
 */
private void step2(Map<String, SomeObject> objectsMap) {
    // Step 2
    final AnotherObject anotherObject = anotherService
            .createAnotherObject(objectsMap);
    if (null != anotherObject) {
        step3(anotherObject);
    } else { // Step 2 failed
        // log and handle
    }
}

/**
 * Explain what step3 does.
 */
private void step3(AnotherObject anotherObject) {
    // Step 3 that gets anotherObject as input and returns something
    // else
}
```

This approach just breaks the method down to smaller methods. The advantage is that each smaller method is only responsible for one thing. And because it is a method you can add javadoc to it. So there is no need for inline comments anymore. Eventually you can give the method better names and omit the javadoc at all.

**Refactor in order to make the steps replaceable at runtime**

If you want to configure the steps that are executed at runtime (e.g. because of some user input) than you must encapsulate them in objects, because your application has references to objects that can be replaced.

Since you want all steps to have a common api you must make it more general.

Start thinking from the clients perspective. How should the steps be executed. E.g.

```
for (Step step : steps) {
    boolean executeNext = step.execute();
    if (!executeNext) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Design a Step interface

```
public interface Step {
    boolean execute();
}
```

How to pass the output of one step as the input to another?

Make an interface

```
public static interface StepInput<T> {
    public T getInput();
}
```

Implement your Steps. An abstract class will help you.

```
public abstract class InputOutputStep<T> implements Step,
        StepInput<T> {

    private T returnValue;

    protected void setReturnValue(T returnValue) {
        this.returnValue = returnValue;
    }

    public T getInput() {
        return returnValue;
    }
}

public class Step1 extends InputOutputStep<Map<String, SomeObject>> {

    private StepInput<Map<String, SomeObject>> stepInput;

    public Step1(StepInput<Map<String, SomeObject>> stepInput) {
        this.stepInput = stepInput;
    }

    public boolean execute() {
        boolean executeNext = false;

        Map<String, SomeObject> objectsMap = stepInput.getInput();
        if (!objectsMap.isEmpty()) {
            // Step 2
            setReturnValue(objectsMap);
            executeNext = true;
        } else { // Step 1 failed
            // log and handle
        }

        return executeNext;
    }
}

public class Step2 extends InputOutputStep<AnotherObject> {

    private StepInput<Map<String, SomeObject>> stepInput;
    private AnotherService anotherService;

    public Step2(AnotherService anotherService,
            StepInput<Map<String, SomeObject>> stepInput) {
        this.anotherService = anotherService;
        this.stepInput = stepInput;
    }

    public boolean execute() {
        boolean executeNext = false;

        Map<String, SomeObject> objectsMap = stepInput.getInput();
        AnotherObject anotherObject = anotherService
                .createAnotherObject(objectsMap);
        if (null != anotherObject) {
            setReturnValue(anotherObject);
            executeNext = true;
        } else { // Step 2 failed
            // log and handle
        }
        return executeNext;
    }
}

public class Step3 extends InputOutputStep<Void> {

    private StepInput<AnotherObject> stepInput;

    public Step3(StepInput<AnotherObject> stepInput) {
        this.stepInput = stepInput;
    }

    public boolean execute() {
        AnotherObject anotherObject = stepInput.getInput();
        setReturnValue(null);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Configure the steps at runtime and execute

```
Step1 step1 = new Step1(stepInput);
Step2 step2 = new Step2(anotherService, step1);
Step step3 = new Step3(step2);

Step[] steps = new Step[]{step1, step2, step3};

for (Step step : steps) {
    boolean executeNext = step.execute();
    if (!executeNext) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution (the one that relates to refactor in order to make the steps replaceable at runtime) and sure going to try it soon. I did try something similar actually but you got there a few points I seem to miss.

Comment: I have a problem with this solution. It seems that T represents both - the input and the output of a step but this does not make sense. In the abstract class InputOutputStep both of the methods refer to the same member. maybe there should be 2 generic type members(for input and output) but this is more or less whet I've been trying to do before posting the question with no success

Comment: To connect two steps one must produce an output that is the input for another. So `T` represents the output of one step that another uses as input. It might be confusing that you call `setReturnValue` with type `T`. But as explained above `T` must be both in order to connect two steps. I hope I could make my thoughts a bit more clear.

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable, I'll give it another shot cause I might have missed your intentions and now I think I get it.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario -where you do lots of things and want to abort and log if any of them fails - is what exception handling is designed for. For example:

```
try {
    // Step 1
    Map<String, SomeObject> objectsMap = someService.createObjectsMap();
    if (objectsMap.isEmpty())
        throw new SomethingWentWrongException("Failed to get object map from service");

    // Step 2
    AnotherObject anotherObject = anotherService.createAnotherObject(objectsMap);
    if(anotherObject == null)
        throw new SomethingWentWrongException("Failed to create another object");

    // Step 3 that gets anotherObject as input and returns something else
} catch(SomethingWentWrongException e) {
    // log and handle
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Ideally, `someService.createObjectsMap` and `anotherService.createAnotherObject` would throw their own exceptions instead of making you check the return value. Then you would only need to write:

```
try {
    Map<String, SomeObject> objectsMap = someService.createObjectsMap();
    AnotherObject anotherObject = anotherService.createAnotherObject(objectsMap);
    // Step 3 that gets anotherObject as input and returns something else
} catch(Exception e) {
    // log and handle
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

(although note that you should only catch `Exception` if you really want to catch *all* failures)

Comment: I don't see how this changes things. Instead of "else" blocks you use the throw declaration which will enforce me to build a series of exceptions (each step will have it's own exception). This way for every new step one needs to add and additional exception should be created as well (unnecessary if you ask me). In addition my services (called from the steps) do not throw any exception, the try/catch mechanism is expensive and make things even uglier (if you ask me), I rather simply having a simple validation check on the step result (such as not null)

Comment: @forhas Are you handling each failure scenario differently?

Comment: Let's suppose I do, but I can validate my results easily, a I mentioned my services handle the exceptions internally and make sure to return an answer that can be validated from the top level (the place that the run the steps)

Answer (score -2):

Options:

1. Memento Pattern:
   With memento, you can store the state of the object. Like when you want to redo and undo things.
   This way, when you have similar methods in step 1 and step 3, you can simply use 1 general method.
   Then, with undo and redo, you know that you have to save your state.
   Think of possibility to save your step number.
2. Strategy pattern:
   With strategy pattern, you are saving the IF-ELSE statement.
   You just have to go to one function, strategy object will determine the rest.
   Think of a router as the strategy class.
   The router will determine the best way, best route, or best process (from several process options).
3. Observer pattern:
   This is something like MVC.
   I always think that observer is a CCTV.
   When something changes, something weird happened, the CCTV admin will know.
   So you have a controller class, which monitors everything, and configures where you have to go next.

Thank you,

Comment: Your answer is pure theoretical and has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: You are not getting better.. If you have an answer to my specific question you are more than welcome to shed some light, but if you just want to throw some patterns in the air and wave some books please spare me.